# Invalid response using ADAL and ADFS

Tags: active-directory, adfs, adal

While building a mobile application in Xamarin I ran into an issue with authentication through ADFS. I'm running AD and ADFS on a VPS and I want the mobile app to authenticate through there to access a Web Api. I have the Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) installed in the app and it seems to be working fine when I use `https://login.windows.net/common` as the authority.

But when I try to use my own domain `https://www.example.com/adfs` as the authority the ADAL request always returns `The authorization server returned an invalid response`.

I tried doing a manual request through my browser like this:

```
https://www.example.com/adfs/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=xxxxxx&resource=xxxxxxxx
```

This request works fine as it shows me the login page, but after a succesful login it redirects to the redirect uri with a general error message. I had to go to the server's ADFS logs to find the following error: `Unsupported token type`.

Am I missing something in the ADFS configuration or ADAL implementation?

Comment: What version of AFS are you using? How have you configured the RP on the AFS side?

Comment: I'm using ADFS 3.0 and everything is configured as default, the RP has both WS-Federation and SAML endpoints added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ADAL uses OAuth not WS-Fed or SAML.

ADFS 3.0 has very limited OAuth support - for full support you need ADFS 4.0.

[This article](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/) describes what you need to do.

https://login.windows.net/common is Azure AD and has full support and hence works.

Note that you need to use PowerShell to configure the RP as per the article.

Comment: Thank you, the method in the article fixed the token issues. The invalid response error turned out to be an issue with the https certificate.